# Apollo GraphQL Client 'Network error: Can't find field XXXX on object undefined' with disableOffline: false

Tags: apollo-client, aws-appsync

I am having trouble using apollo-client version 2.4.6 to query my AWS AppSync endpoint.
I can successfully query the AWS AppSync endpoint using a curl command, but the exact same
GraphQL executed over the Apollo client is returning "Can't find field getTickets on object undefined."

I am a newby at GraphQL and Apollo.  Am I doing something stupid to cause that error?  Why does it say NetworkError?  Why is the object undefined?

**EDIT: I noticed that if I pass `disableOffline: true` in the constructor to `AWSAppSyncClient` then it starts working.  Why?  Why is the default client behavior with `disableOffline: false` not working?**

Here is my super simple schema.graphql deployed at AWS:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  getTickets: [EmmDDavidTickets]
  @aws_api_key
}

type EmmDDavidTickets @aws_api_key {
  ticketNumber: ID!
  pnrNumber: String
}
```

Here is the curl command that works to query that endpoint at AWS.  Note the valid response:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "x-api-key: --REDACTED--" https://wm3mz6anrjbrfpgbewnyyrio3u.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql -d '{ "query": "query list {\ngetTickets { ticketNumber\n pnrNumber\n }\n}"}'

{"data":{"getTickets":[{"ticketNumber":"12345","pnrNumber":null},{"ticketNumber":"0001020202020","pnrNumber":"ABC123"}]}}
```

Here is my NodeJS code to execute the same query using Apollo:

```
const apiKey ='--REDACTED--';
const region = 'us-east-1';
const type = 'API_KEY';
const url = 'https://wm3mz6anrjbrfpgbewnyyrio3u.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql';

const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const query = gql(`
query list {
  getTickets {
      ticketNumber
  }
}`);

// Set up Apollo client
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: url,
    region: region,
    auth: {
        type: type,
        apiKey: apiKey,
    },
    disableOffline: false
});

client.hydrated().then(function (client) {
    //Now run a query
    client.query({ query: query })
        .then(function logData(data) {
            console.log('results of query: ', data);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Here is the error response from Apollo:

```
ApolloError: Network error: Can't find field getTickets on object undefined.
    at new ApolloError (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:85:32)
    at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1039:45
    at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1411:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1410:22
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1405:26)
    at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:988:35 {
  graphQLErrors: [],
  networkError: Error: Can't find field getTickets on object undefined.
      at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:429:27
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at StoreReader.diffQueryAgainstStore (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:426:36)
      at StoreReader.readQueryFromStore (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:401:25)
      at processOfflineQuery (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/offline-link.js:154:34)
      at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/link/offline-link.js:110:28
      at new Subscription (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:183:34)
      at Observable.subscribe (/Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:262:14)
      at /Users/dyoung/workspace//appsync_javascript_test/node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/client.js:182:67,
  message: "Network error: Can't find field getTickets on object undefined.",
  extraInfo: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [Apollo Docs on local state management](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/):

> We need to write an initial state to the cache before the query is run
>   to prevent it from erroring out.

I had the almost same error thrown out when I did not initialise the state in the Apollo's InMemoryCache.

To initialize the state for AWSAppSyncClient, you can refer to [React-Native + Apollo-Link-State + AWS Appsync : Defaults are not stored in cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293930/react-native-apollo-link-state-aws-appsync-defaults-are-not-stored-in-cach), and https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/pull/96

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I never would have guessed this.  I think iti is crazy for the default usage of the API to require such cache priming without throwing an error that does not indicate what you need to do.

Comment: This issue comment is also worth noting https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/453#issuecomment-520246437, `redux-offline` will stuck when `auth.jwtToken` throws.